# Android Two Flavors with same Service Package

Tags: android

I created multiple Flavours of an App in Android Studio from same code base. In the app i have a service in package

```
com.app.xyz.service
```

I change application id for each flavour  as below

```
applicationId "com.app2.flavour1"
```

and

```
applicationId "com.app2.flavour2"
```

in **build.graddle**

but Service Package remains same because its in shared code for each flavour.
Now Issue is, when I install both flavours with different app IDs in same device, each app instantiate the SERVICE TWICE.

How to isolate while keeping the same code of service class.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as yours.

The only solution I have found for now is the following :

- create a service definition by flavor in the manifest file
- create a service implementation in each flavors (just the minimum code : onCreate, ...).
- create a "helper" class in the "main" project with the code of my original service implementation

Not very "beautiful" but my project contains only two flavors so it still readable and maintainable

Comment: how can i initiate that service from MAIN flavour ??

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue as below.

I was sending Broadcasts to communicate between Service and Other part of the application. I added prefix with action for each App through BuildConfig.IDENTIFIER.

Now Each App was only listening to its own specific actions so each flavour was not interfering with other.